# How to include *forked* github branch as dependency in package.json

Tags: react-native, github, npm, package.json

I'm trying to include a `fork` of https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react-native

When I include `"@segment/analytics-react-native": "^1.1.0",` in my package.json

I see the following

```
├── README.md
├── RNAnalytics.podspec
├── android
├── build
├── ios
├── package.json
└── src
```

But if I include the fork of the library as `"analytics-react-native": "account_name/analytics-react-native#master",`, I see

```
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── RELEASING.md
├── package.json
├── packages
└── tsconfig.json
```

Of course, build fails with the forked version.. 
How Can I use the forked version as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
"git://github.com/your-account/analytics-react-native.git#branch_name": "^1.1.0"
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies). `#commit-ish` can be any valid gitref (such as a commit, branch, or tag).

Edit: Ah, per the edit, the repo is a monorepo with the desired package.json a few levels down. This is currently [an open request in Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4725). There's a similar request for npm [which was closed](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974). There are some good suggestions for compromises in that thread, but there's no one solution to that problem yet.

Comment: umm, so this library is peculiar.. can you take a look at the difference of the directory structure .. of the original repo and forked repo..

Comment: yeah, I see now that it's a monorepo. There's not a good solution to that right now. There are some suggestions for additional tools such as gitpkg or lerna, but they're compromises, rather than actual solutions right now.

Comment: so how do I use my edited version? I guess I could just manually copy them over.

Comment: You could put it in a vendor/ directory, then just use `./vendor/analytics-react-native/packages/core`rather than `@segment/analytics-react-native`. The could be done with a git submodule.